# Property initialized in init, not updated in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios

I want to display a loader after 0.5 second when the view has been created.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.loaded = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.loader = [self newLoader];
    self.loaded = YES;
    self.loaderTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(showLoader) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loader];
}

- (void)showLoader
{
    if (self.loaded == NO) {
        [self.loader show:YES];
    }
}
```

Normally with `self.loaded = YES` in `viewDidLoad` the loader should not be displayed. But it still appears.
Should I put `self.loaded = YES` in the `init` so it does not get displayed ?

EDIT:
If I initialize `self.loaded` in `viewDidLoad` rather than in 'init', it doesn't show up. But why I can't initialize 'self.loaded' in 'init' method so that loader should not show up?

Comment: What is `loader`?  It looks like a UIView subclass.  Why wouldn't it show after you add it as a subview to the main view?

Comment: It's a [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Comment: But the problem is that the property `loaded` has not the correct value in `- (void)showLoader`.

Comment: the `–viewDidLoad` is not equal to `–viewWillAppear` or `–viewDidAppear`. the `–viewDidLoad` invoked when the instance of `UIViewController` loads into the memory, but it does not mean it appears, so probably your method runs _before_ the view appears, and that is why it is not working. I highly recommend you to discover the essentials of the lifecycle of the `UIViewController` objects.

Comment: I think when you  type [self newloader] it get a running loader and you add it as a subview , so it by default is shown

Answer (score 0):

Change your initializer from `self.loaded` to `_loaded`

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _loaded = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

When you use `self`, it calls `viewDidLoad`, therefore it gets executed before initializer execution is completed.